# jquery a form submitted with return false; gets lost cannot submit twice?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

This is very hard to explain but it seems like my form gets garbage collected or something even though its `return false;` on submitting so it never actually gets proceeded, I need to be able to submit it multiple times if possible or else I have to always refresh page to retry again.. It's the green button `Pay with Credit/Debit/Gift Card`

check out my website [website url](http://www.HighGamer.com/AOInternational)

In my chrome console I get this error

```
Uncaught TypeError: $(...).tukivalidator is not a function
    at HTMLAnchorElement.<anonymous> ((index):358)
    at HTMLAnchorElement.dispatch (jquery-1.8.2.min.js:2)
    at HTMLAnchorElement.h (jquery-1.8.2.min.js:2)
```

even though the `tukivalidator` works the first time, the second time it doesn't exist or something.. and even if I remove `tukivalidator` the next part of code fails too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery gets loaded again. This causes all previous references to jQuery to break. Consider identifying where in your code base that you're re-injecting the `<script>` into the DOM, and you'll solve your problem.

Comment: I know its this new piece of code I added `$.tukibox("load", "braintreegateway.php`  can you tell me what needs to be fixed?

Comment: I think I figured it out the content that was loaded by ajax also had jQuery script in there so it loaded that script twice I guess?

Comment: @SSpoke That seems absolutely correct. Resolve that and you'll be good!